# Splitting Up Excel Worksheet By Unique Column Values Using Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am attempting to separate an Excel spreadsheet with multiple email addresses in the same column to a separate workbook based on each unique email address value.

My intent is to copy and paste each group of rows with the same email address value into a separate workbook I can then attach to an email message and send as an Excel attachment to each corresponding recipient within the new workbook.

So far I have only been able to copy and paste rows for a specific value into a new workbook and then send that file to the email address in a specific cell location, in this case "O2".

```
import openpyxl

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'file.xlsx', data_only=True)
wb2 = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet1 = wb1['Sheet1']
sheet2 = wb2['Sheet2']


header = sheet[1:1]
listH =[]
for h in header:
    listH.append(h.value)
sheet2.append(listH)


colOfInterest= 15 # This is the column which contains the email addresses
for rowNum in range(2, sheet1.max_row +1):
    if sheet1.cell(row=rowNum, column=colOfInterest).value is not None: 
        listA = []
        row = sheet1[rowNum:rowNum] 
        for cell in row:
            listA.append(cell.value) 
        if listA[15]  == "email@domainname.com":
            sheet2.append(listA)


wb1.save('TestList1.xlsx')


import win32com.client as win32

outlook = win32.Dispatch("outlook.application")

mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

mail.To = (str(sheet1['O2'].value))

mail.Cc = (str(sheet1['P2'].value))

mail.Subject = "Subject Line Goes Here"

mail.Body = ""

mail.HTMLBody = """ Email content goes here."""

attachment1  = "List1.xlsx"
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment1)

mail.Send()
```

The code listed above works only for specific email address values. I have yet to figure out how to have python loop through the entire original spreadsheet to create the separate Excel attachment for each unique email address value and email it to the appropriate recipient.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Can you post some example sheet? I'm reading it multiple times and getting lost... I get that you have list of email address column in a.xlsx

Comment: Sure, here is a link to an image of the spreadsheet.

https://postimg.cc/62R0B60P

Comment: Use `ws.iter_rows(min_row=…, min_col=…, max_col=…)` or simply `ws['O']`